# Как получить URI изображения, загруженного в ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, uri

Изображение в ImageView загружается с использованием Picasso . Как поделиться этим изображением, если у ImageView нет getter'a для uri? Может есть какой то другой вариант?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В классе [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) есть методы [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) и [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()), которые позволяют привязать к элементу любой объект.

Поэтому так:

```
imageView.setTag(url);

url = (String)imageView.getTag();
```

Comment: url ? Мы говорим про URI необходимый для shareIntent

Comment: @Новичок В качестве тэга можно положить любой объект, в том числе и URI